# Two sets having the same subset sums.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation, additive-combinatorics

I was trying to prove the following
**Proposition:**

> Let $A=\{a_1,\ldots, a_k\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\ldots, b_k\}$ be two multisets (repetition is allowed)
> with $|A|=|B|=k$. Also $0\le a_1\le a_2\le\ldots \le a_k$ and $0\le b_1\le
>  \ldots \le b_k$. If $A$ and $B$ have the same subset sums, then $A=B$.

Same subset sums means that for every $A_i\subseteq A$, there is a $B_i\subseteq B$ such that the sum of elements of $A_i$ is equal to the sum of elements of $B_i$. Also just to clarify, if a number arises $x$ times as a subset sum from $A$, then it should arise $x$ times from $B$.
I believed that I found a proof:

Clearly, $a_1=b_1$ since they are the smallest subset sums of $A$ and $B$ respectively.
Let $S(A
_i)$ denote the sum of elements of $A_i$.
We must also have $\sum_{A_i\subseteq A}x^{S(A_i)}=\prod_{i=1}^k(1+x^{a_i})=\prod_{i=1}^k(1+x^{b_i})=\sum_{B_i\subseteq B}x^{S(B_i)}$ (since they have the same subset sums).
Since $a_1=b_1$, we cancel from the products the factors $(1+x^{a_1})$ and $(1+x^{b_1}$) and we are left with $\prod_{i=2}^k(1+x^{a_i})=\prod_{i=2}^k(1+x^{b_i})$. This shows that the sets $A-\{a_1\}, B-\{b_1\}$ have the same subset sums. We repeat this process until $a_k=b_k$.

> Question: Is there another more "simple" proof of this proposition?
> (If the proof I presented is correct)

Comment: Just a comment to point out that your $A$ and $B$ are not exactly *sets* per se, since you are allowing repeated elements.

Comment: @MikeF you are right, I made an edit.

Comment: What are these terms? Are they natural numbers? Integers? Real numbers?

Comment: @MiloBrandt does it matter? Let's say natural numbers, because I am interested to this version of the problem.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Negative numbers would make the result false - e.g. {-1, 0, 1} vs {-1, 1} or less trivially {-4, -2, -1, 1, 2, 4} vs {-3,-2,-1,-1,1,1,2,3}. But your proof looks fine for positive integers

Comment: @MiloBrandt the multisets must have the same number of elements

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5} vs {-7,-4,-2,-1,-1,1,1,2,4,7} then - lots of set have an interval of integers around $0$ as their subset sums.

Comment: @MiloBrandt the multisets you gave do not have the same subset sums. From the first multiset the number $14$ appears twice but from the second multiset $14$ appears four times.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Oh! You should edit that into the question - the definition of "same subset sums" you put in the question does permit my example, so I think you didn't quite write down what you meant; you need to instead talk either about the multiset of possible sums or ask that there be a bijection between $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ preserving the subset sums.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I wrote that for every $A_i$, there is a $B_i$ such that they have equal sums. Isn't this equivalent?

Comment: $1,1,-2$ and $-1,-1,2$ both have sumsets $-2,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction.   Once you have established $(a_1,...,a_i)=(b_1,...,b_i)$, remove $S(a_1,...,a_i)$ from S(A) and $S(b_1,...,b_i)$ from S(B). The lowest sum that remains is $a_{i+1}=b_{i+1}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, the idea is: It is true for $i$, and show that it is true for $i+1$. We have two multisets $A$ and $B$ with $|A|=|B|=i+1$ with equal subset sums. Then? Could you be more specific?

Comment: No, $0\le i \lt k$.  You have established it for $i=1$, that $a_1=b_1$.  Then the lowest sum that is neither the empty sum nor $a_1$ must be $a_2$. The lowest sum that is neither the empty sum, $a_1,a_2$ nor $a_1+a_2$ is $a_3$

Comment: I get your point. But the lowest sum could be $a_1+a_2$ or $a_3$. You can't know for sure. This proves that $a_1=b_1$ and that $a_2=b_2$. But what if $a_1+a_2=b_3$?

Comment: You know what $a_1$ and $a_2$ are by now, so you know what $a_1+a_2$ is.  It needn't be small.  But once you have removed it, and the same numbers ftom S(B), the smallest numbers in each set are $a_3=b_3$

Comment: Interesting. Let me think of it for a while..

Comment: Excuse me but how this works if $A=\{1, 2, 4, ...\}$ and $B=\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$? The four smallest subset sums from $A$ are $1, 2, 1+2, 4$ and from $B$ are $1, 2, 3, 1+3$.

Comment: From $B$ are $1,2,3,1+2$  So 3 appears twice

Comment: Ok it seems correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your basic approach of induction on the number of elements in the multisets is a good one.  I think you can simplify it by saying that any $A_i$ that includes $a_1$ must have a matching $B_i$ that includes an element equal to $b_1$ because otherwise $A_i\setminus a_1$ would have no matching multiset.  Now you can delete $a_1,b_1$ from any pair that have both of them and get to your claim that $A\setminus a_1$ and $B \setminus b_1$ have mathching subset sums.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure I understand your idea here. What is the problem if for example $a_1+a_9=b_3+b_4+b_5$? Could you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: It is only a problem if there is no sum $a_1+a_9=$ some $b$'s that includes $b_1$  If there is, you just consider the sum that is left after removing both of them.  If there is not, there will be no sum of $b$'s equal to $a_9$ because if there were you could add $a_1$ and $b_1$ to it.

Comment: Excuse me for being stubborn. But it could be possible that $a_9=b_1+b_6$ (for example). How could you add $b_1$ to the RHS? We would get $a_1+a_9=b_1+b_1+b_6$. I really do want to follow your argument.

Comment: You are not being stubborn, that is a good point.  I'll have to think on it.